# increasing row by 1 in arraylist java

Tags: java, apache-poi

how I want my code to work is when the the iterator found the string "B" it will then go for the next row to find the "D" which contain in the next row like this:

```
|row 2 | A | B | C |
--------------------
|row 3 | D | E | E |
```

but the problem that I face right now is the row wont move to the next row. Pardon me because I am still a noob regarding looping in java. please help me thank you.

```
        int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
        int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

        // row
        for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

            // cell
            for (int i = 0; i < r.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
                String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(stringcell);
            }
            ListIterator<String> lt = al.listIterator();

            while(lt.hasNext()){
             element = lt.next();
                if (element.equals("B") {
                        rowNum++;

                        while (lt.hasNext()) {
                        element = lt.next();
                        if (element.equals("D")) {
                            System.out.println("found");
                            break;

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("false");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }


                            break;
                    }
         }
}
```

Comment: You increment your row number (`rowNum++`), but you do not actually get the next row or update your iterator (`lt`) before looking for `"D"`.

Comment: @dave "update your iterator(lt)" ? can you please explain to me?

Comment: `lt` is the iterator over the elements in the _current_ row. This is unchanged by simply incrementing your row number. Hence you will never find an element from the _next_ row.

Comment: @dave I know, that is my problem now. I don't know how to do it................. help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general outline of your code could be

```
String lookFor = "B";
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
    Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

    boolean found = false;

    // cell
    for (int i = 0; i < r.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
        String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        if (stringcell .equals(lookFor)) {
               rowNum++;
               lookFor = "D";
               found = true;
               break;
        }
    }    
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(lookFor  + " found");
    }        
    else {
        System.out.println(lookFor  + " not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: `found` is never set to `true`.

Comment: No worries. Your solution would match the case where the rows with `"B"` and `"D"` have an intervening row(s).

Comment: @dave Yep, not quite following the OP's requirements, but I think that could be prevented by exiting if not found

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through the rows of the spreadsheet looking for a `"B"` on a row. If you find one, then you want to look for a `"D"` on the next row. Something like this might do the trick.

```
boolean lookforD = false; foundD = false;
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
    Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < r.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
        String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        al.add(stringcell);
    }
    ListIterator<String> lt = al.listIterator();
    while (lt.hasNext()) {
         element = lt.next();
         if (!lookForD) {
             if (element.equals("B")) {
                 lookForD = true;
                 break;
             }
         } else {
             if (element.equals("D")) {
                 foundD = true;
                 break;
             }
             if (!lt.hasNext()) {
                 lookForD = false;
             }
         }
     }
     if (foundD) {
         break;
     }
 }
```

N.B. This is pretty rough and I've only checked it by hand. You'll need to make sure it compiles. Further, if you find a `"B"` on one line, but there's no `"D"` on the next line, then we should look for `"B"` on that same line. This code doesn't handle that case.